# Force database flush using Propel

Tags: php, orm, propel

Here is an example of my tables

```
<table name="user">
  <column name="name" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
</table>

<table name="environment">
  <column name="user_id" type="integer" size="11" required="true" />
  <column name="insertion_time" type="timestamp" required="true" phpName="InsertionTime" />

  <foreign-key foreignTable="user" phpName="User">
    <reference local="user_id" foreign="id"/>
  </foreign-key>
</table>
```

I want to insert some `environment` linked with their `user`.

```
function insertEnvironment($id) {
    $user = findUser($id);

    $env = new Environment();
    $env->setUser($user);
    $env->setInsertionTime(new DateTime());

    $env->save();
}

function findUser($id) {
    $user = UserQuery::create()->filterByUserId($id)->findOneOrCreate();
    return $user;
}
```

I can insert more than one `environment` on the same page but I don't want to recreate the `user` if it already exists.

Right now, it creates one `user` each time I insert an `environment` (during the same page execution, afterwards it works as expected).

How can I force the insertion of the `user` so that the next time I want to access it it already exists?

Is there another way to achieve this without forcing a "flush" ?
I don't want to keep track of the users by hand.

**Edit**: I changed the way I create the user (code above edited), but it does not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround, which is to disable the *pooling*.

```
Propel::disableInstancePooling();
```

To add in the setup.php file.
But it then disable the feature completely, which drains performances down.

Comment: More than 5 years later, no I can't. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a new method in your ActiveRecord model ?

Something like that for instance:

```
<?php

class User extends BaseUser
{
    // Override the generated method
    public function addEnvironment($env)
    {
        $env->setInsertionTime(new DateTime());

        parent::addEnvironment($env);
    }
}
```

Then, start by finding or creating your user:

```
<?php

$user = UserQuery::create()->filterByUserId($id)->findOneOrCreate();

for ($i = 0; $i < $nbEnvironments; $i++) {
    $user->addEnvironment(new Environment());
}

// Save all
$user->save();
```

You won't get more than one user object, and you'll be able to use only one transaction for all your data manipulations. As you want to insert some environments to a user, it seems better to add this logic to the User ActiveRecord model.

Comment: Well sadly I cannot get the environments like that. They come one after the other (like a logging system) and there is no way to do a loop like you did.
So you confirm there is now way to force a flush?

Comment: If they come one after the other, then you also can save the whole at the end of your script, isn't it? The loop is just here to show you, you can add all your environments before to save the user.

Comment: As I said in the question: I could, but findOneOrCreate() does not seems to find a user that has already been created in memory, but not persisted. I could keep a list of all users in memory by myself, but isn't it the point of Propel to manage it for me?

Comment: (I accepted the question to give you the bounty, but I would appreciate more incentives about this behavior. Thanks :))

Comment: It could be an unsupported feature... I'm not sure it should work this way. I'm gonna checking the code.